# QBFC Billadd Transaction

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbfc

I have an application that interfaces with QuickBooks and I am using the BILLADD transaction.  The application pulls bill transactions from another data base and updates quickbooks.  The billadd transactions that we are pushing to quickbooks have several expense lines. Some of the expense lines are negative(credits) to the vendor.  I can manually enter a negative number on a new bill, but the get an error when trying to do it programmatically.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to do this with billadd or do I need a different transaction type to add the credits?

Scott

Comment: Please post the XML being generated. Try moving the credit around (first, middle or last) in the expense lines and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the total of the bill is not negative, you should be able to add negative expenses. If you need to enter a negative bill, you would need to enter it as a IVendorCreditAddRq. I tested it with adding a bill with -10, +100, and -50 line expenses and was able to save it without a problem.

Could you post your request and the response you are getting?